# SQLite not selecting date

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My SQlite database in my app stores the date in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. I want to query a transaction that happened on a certain month of a year but my code is not working :

```
SELECT COUNT(id_sale) AS total_transactions,sold_to, 
strftime('%m', sale_date) AS month, 
strftime('%Y', sale_date) AS year,
sale_date FROM sales  WHERE  month=5 AND year=2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I discovered that for some reason I had to do some casting for it to work.

```
    SELECT COUNT(id_sale) AS total_transactions,sold_to,
CAST(strftime('%m', sale_date) AS INTEGER) month, 
    CAST(strftime('%Y', sale_date) AS INTEGER) year,
    sale_date FROM sales  WHERE  month=5
```

Answer (score 0):

As your date values are strings, you need no casting. You can compare directly with string values in your first select statement

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(id_sale) AS total_transactions,
   sold_to, 
   strftime('%m', sale_date) AS month, 
   strftime('%Y', sale_date) AS year,
   sale_date 
FROM sales  
   WHERE  month='05' AND year='2015'
```

Comment: You have to consider the format:  **'05'** instead of  **'5'**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple string matching:

```
... WHERE sale_date LIKE "2015-05-%"
```

I omitted result columns from query as I do not understand what is your intent, mixing aggregate function without `GROUP BY` and duplicating data.